# Android Studio assert not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, assert, android-studio-3.1

I'm calling `findViewById` and Android Studio (version 3.1, stable) prompts me to put an assertion:

[image]

When I select it, it adds the following line above the selected line:

`assert v != null;`

Great. I run the app, and the `View v` is null. However, assertion doesn't work and it jumps to the line below it in debugger:

[image]

How is this even possible? It was Android Studio's own suggestion, and I didn't change a thing. Its own recommendation/autogenerated code is not working. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Java assertions [are disabled by default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html). Which VM options are you running with?

Comment: @MickMnemonic it's whatever Android Studio 3.1 ships with. I haven't changed it. So, if it's disabled, why does Android Studio highlight the code and recommend me to add it? It just adds great confusion.

Comment: Haven't worked with AS, so unfortunately I don't know why the linter suggests this. Personally, I never use `assert` (and [here is a good discussion about some reasons why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537609/is-it-good-practice-to-use-assert-in-java)). Instead I prefer _explicit_ (not disableable) validators such as [Guava Preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) (might not be available in Android).

Comment: It is surprising why AS is behaving like that. However, if you don't mind looking beyond assertions, there are two things you can do here.

Comment: 1. Instead of assert statement, use something like   `if (v == null && BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e("your_tag", "your_message"); else { mapView = v.findViewById (R.id.MapView);}`

Comment: 2. If you know the parent activity of the MapView, you can just call findViewById on the layout root of the parent activity. In or after Creation of activity, (basically once onCreate is called), you can rest assured that the root layout of the parent activity will never be null. So you need not check for `if(root !=null) mapView = root.findViewById(R.id.MapView);`

Comment: 3. You can have a look at ButterKnife and it can map all your required views with Java Objects at compile time, without you having to use `findViewById` at all. It reduces boilerplate and runtime code. So if your project is decently sized, you can maybe look at Butterknife.

Comment: @Raymond232 thank you, I'll look at ButterKnife, it sounds good. But my main point is that why AS recommends me to take some action that does absolutely nothing in default settings in the first place.

Comment: That is still surprising. Because I put an assert statement in my code and it threw me this warning,

"  Assertions are unreliable in Dalvik and unimplemented in ART. Use BuildConfig.DEBUG conditional checks instead. less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Assertions are not checked at runtime. There are ways to request that they be used by Dalvik (adb shell setprop debug.assert 1), but note that this is not implemented in ART (the newer runtime), and even in Dalvik the property is ignored in many places and can not be relied upon.

Comment: Instead, perform conditional checking inside if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { } blocks. That constant is a static final boolean which is true in debug builds and false in release builds, and the Java compiler completely removes all code inside the if-body from the app.  For example, you can replace assert speed > 0 with if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && !(speed > 0)) { \ throw new AssertionError() }.  (Note: This lint check does not flag assertions purely asserting nullness or non-nullness; these are typically more intended for tools usage than runtime checks.)

Comment: More info: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65183 ."

So AS in fact clearly warns me against assertions. I am surprised it suggests you to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, (as stated in the comments) assertions are disabled by default but encouraged by Android Studio.

In this manner, the "problem" can be classified as a misleading UX issue rather than a technical problem.